# How can I make ids as array in alloy

Tags: titanium

I am making many view objects in xml.

```
<ImageView id="Keyboard0" />
<ImageView id="Keyboard1" />
<ImageView id="Keyboard2" />
<ImageView id="Keyboard3" />
<ImageView id="Keyboard4" />
<ImageView id="Keyboard5" />
```

I would like to make these id's as array.

For example, I would like to access each objects like this

```
$.Keyboard[0].image = 'img/test.png';
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your ids using this kind of for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    $['Keyboard' + i].image = 'img/test.png';
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks,but its not cool.....,I think I should make the each view file and make these as array.

Comment: 'app/lib' is just convienient directory to put CommonJS modules when you are using Alloy. You can use CommonJS with plain Titanium SDK, too. Take a look on this tutorial: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium